# Form fields gets cleared on POST data with knockout binding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, knockout.js, data-binding

I'm working with PHP on backend with Slim microframework, in case it be relevant.

Well, the problem is that the form gets cleared after submit. The server return an error code, in case of error, ofcourse, and the error message is showed to the user, but the fields are clean.

I must mention that I'm using the jquery-validation plugin.

HTML

```
<form action="{{ path_for('save_data') }}" method="POST" id="myForm" name="myForm" data-bind="submit: sendForm">
    <input type="text" name="foo" data-bind="value: foo" required>
    <button type="submit">Save data</button>
</form>
```

Javascript/Knockout JS

```
function MyView($) {
   var self = this;

   self.foo = ko.observable();

   /* ... code ... */

   self.sendForm = function(theForm) {
       if (!$(theForm).valid()) {
           return;
       }

       $.post(theForm.action, ko.toJS(self.foo), function(response) {
           alert(response);
       })
       .fail(function(failResponse) {
         alert(failResponse);
       });
   };
}

ko.applyBindigs(new MyView(jQuery));
```

Just for better understanding, the server code is something like this:

```
public function postSaveData($request, $response) {
    if (TRUE) { // Some validations here
        return $response->withJson("Error message", 400);
    }
    // save
    return $response->withJson("OK", 200);
}
```

**UPDATE**

After some tests, occurs to me to test with pure javascript code, with no jQuery. Like as follows:

```
self.sendForm = function(theForm) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("Response text: ", xhttp.responseText);
        }
        else if (this.status == 400) {
            console.log("Response text: ", xhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", formElement.action, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(ko.toJS(self.imovel));
};
```

And voilá! Form perfect filled, as before send data. Somehow jQuery post is clearing the form.

Comment: Is `alert(failResponse);` executed or does the form submit to the action url and a new page is loaded? Not sure if knockout submit handler needs a `event.preventdefault`or `return false` to prevent the form from actually being submitted (default behavior when submit button is clicked).

Comment: Yes, `alert(failResponse);` is fired and the page is not loaded. Look this from knockoutjs docs: [If you do want to let the form submit like a normal HTML form, just return true from your submit handler.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html) I will try return false.

Comment: Nope. Returning false changes nothing.